# Auto download all the images shown in the Webview

Tags: android

**My Code:-**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);
    // defining the WebView
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
    // Websetting can be used to define several web related settings.
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    // Enabling JAVASCRIPT
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    // providing navigational access
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    // loading the URL
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://abcd.com");
}
```

Its the simplest webview anyone will find out there, and i want to do some modification there but am unable to, so plz help me with it.

The site i am opening contains a lot of images, now  i want to know, when a website is accessed all the images and text it contains are download to show it on the UI and when we close the page all of it is lost,if i guessed it right.To download a image, one will have to specifically download it. Like we do in Opera Browser or any other one.

**So i want to download all the image my webview opens in the UI into an dir (path known /sdcard/pics) on my SDCard automatically.** Is there a way?

Comment: @hai bison READ this line twice "but am unable to, so plz help me with it." before talking about respect and thank you for your input(thats your share of respect)

Comment: Kid seriously!!...Here is some english lesson for you grandpa, I : the nominative singular pronoun, used by a speaker in referring to himself or herself.

Comment: Guilty. Sorry, next time I will also check for the possible grammar errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to using the cache directory approach is to intercept all requests to images on-the-fly, as the `WebView` loads them. You can set a `WebViewClient` to your `WebView` that implements one of the following methods:

- [onLoadResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onLoadResource%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) (since API lvl 1)
- [shouldInterceptRequest](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) (since API lvl **11**)

The first method should work on all devices out there, but will probably result in downloading the resource twice: once manually to save it in a specific directory on the SD card, and once by the `WebView` itself. The second method allows you to return the downloaded resource after saving it somewhere, effectively resulting in just a single download.

You should able to find plenty of examples here on SO or by querying your favourite search engine.

Comment: thnx...i was confused and all i needed was a push in the right direction. Btw can i use shouldInterceptRequest on API8 with the help of Support lib?

Comment: @evilmage93: No, unfortunately all WebKit stuff is not part of the support library.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable cache on the WebView and save all the images from the cache to whatever location you need.

To enable cache, use the following code:

```
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 1024 * 8);
```

You can find information about saving cache contents in [Saving the Android WebView cache on the SD card](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2012/01/saving-the-android-webview-cache-on-the-sd-card/)

Comment: nice tutorial, thnx the help.